# Examples of Context Free Languages

Tags: context-free

I'm having a hard time thinking of context free languages. The only example I've been able to think of is $0^n1^n$, but I'm having a hard time thinking of any others. Can I get some examples?

Comment: For a start, all regular languages are context free.

Comment: And we know that all regular languages must be able to be constructed by a DFA. So a language such as a^nb is not regular, right? Because n could be infinite

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. $\{a^nb| n\ge0\}$ _is_ regular, $n$ can be arbitrarily large, but for any given string, is always finite. You can construct a DFA for it. Additionally, the implication I made is one directional. A language that is not regular could still be context free, like the example in your question.

Comment: If a language is regular then it's CF, correct?

Comment: Below your question there is a button, marked "context-free". Click on it, and get inspired.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some of the examples of context free languages

- $\{ w \in \{0,1\}^*\mid \ w$ contains at least three ones }
- $\{ w \in \{0,1\}^*\mid \ w = w^{R}$ and $\mid w \mid $ is even  }
- $\{ w \in \{0,1\}^*\mid \ $ the length of $w$ is odd and the middle symbol is $0$ }
- $\{ a^{i} b^{j} c^{k} \mid \ i,j,k \ge 0 $ and $ i + j = k $ }
- $\{ a^{i} b^{j} c^{k} \mid \ i,j,k \ge 0, $ and $ i = k  $ or $i = k$ }
- $\phi$

**Reference :** https://web.njit.edu/~marvin/cs341/hw/hwsoln05.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the link to Nakayama's material. It is helpful for me studying this at a completely different university. I believe however (maybe wrong) the OP was probably interested in context free (non-regular) language examples, specifically for using them as examples in proofs or homework. For others - in Nakayama's examples above, the first one is regular while the others are not. I found this thread with almost the same question as the OP. I was looking for examples of context free languages other than the quintessential one listed. And not interested in regular.

Answer (score 1):

More general examples of context-free languages which are not regular are the [Dyck languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language) of balanced parentheses of several types. A 1-type Dyck language contains words such as (), (()), ()(), and so on. A 2-type Dyck language contains words such as ([]), ()[], [([()([])])[]], and so on.

The [Chomsky–Schützenberger representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtzenberger_representation_theorem) states that, in some sense, Dyck languages are the most general type of context-free languages.